# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exists

My query is as follows, and contains a subquery within it:

```
 select count(distinct dNum)
 from myDB.dbo.AQ
 where A_ID in 
  (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (0.1) PERCENT A_ID, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT dNum) AS ud 
 FROM         myDB.dbo.AQ
 WHERE     M > 1 and B = 0 
 GROUP BY A_ID ORDER BY ud DESC)
```

The error I am receiving is ...

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not
> introduced with EXISTS.`

When I run the sub-query alone, it returns just fine, so I am assuming there is some issue with the main query?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

You can't return two (or multiple) columns in your subquery to do the comparison in the `WHERE A_ID IN (subquery)` clause - which column is it supposed to compare `A_ID` to? Your subquery must only return the one column needed for the comparison to the column on the other side of the `IN`. So the query needs to be of the form:

```
SELECT * From ThisTable WHERE ThisColumn IN (SELECT ThatColumn FROM ThatTable)
```

You also want to add sorting so you can select just from the top rows, but you don't need to return the COUNT as a column in order to do your sort; sorting in the `ORDER` clause is independent of the columns returned by the query.

Try something like this:

```
select count(distinct dNum) 
from myDB.dbo.AQ 
where A_ID in
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (0.1) PERCENT A_ID
    FROM myDB.dbo.AQ 
    WHERE M > 1 and B = 0
    GROUP BY A_ID 
    ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT dNum) DESC)
```

Answer (score 111):

You should return only one column and one row in the where query where you assign the returned value to a variable. Example:

```
select * from table1 where Date in (select * from Dates) -- Wrong
select * from table1 where Date in (select Column1,Column2 from Dates) -- Wrong
select * from table1 where Date in (select Column1 from Dates) -- OK
```

Comment: It doesn't helped me. Gives me the same error. Specifying the column instead of `*` helped me.

Answer (score 18):

It's complaining about

```
COUNT(DISTINCT dNum) AS ud
```

inside the subquery. Only one column can be returned from the subquery unless you are performing an exists query. I'm not sure why you want to do a count on the same column twice, superficially it looks redundant to what you are doing. The subquery here is only a *filter* it is not the same as a join. i.e. you use it to restrict data, not to specify what columns to get back.

Comment: Sometimes, you can join against query results and that will solve the problem!

Answer (score 7):

Apart from very good responses here, you could try this as well if you want to use your sub query as is.

**Approach:**

1) Select the desired column (Only 1) from your sub query

2) Use where to map the column name

**Code:**

```
 SELECT count(distinct dNum)
 FROM myDB.dbo.AQ
 WHERE A_ID in 
   (
    SELECT A_ID 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (0.1) PERCENT A_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT dNum) AS ud 
          FROM         myDB.dbo.AQ
          WHERE     M > 1 and B = 0 
          GROUP BY A_ID ORDER BY ud DESC
         ) a 
   )
```

Answer (score 6):

Just in case it helps someone, here's what caused this error for me:
I needed a procedure to return json but I left out the *for json path*:

```
set @jsonout = (SELECT ID, SumLev, Census_GEOID, AreaName, Worksite 
            from CS_GEO G (nolock) 
                join @allids a on g.ID = a.[value] 
            where g.Worksite = @worksite)
```

When I tried to save the stored procedure, it threw the error.  I fixed it by adding *for json path* to the code at the end of the procedure:

```
set @jsonout = (SELECT ID, SumLev, Census_GEOID, AreaName, Worksite 
            from CS_GEO G (nolock) 
                join @allids a on g.ID = a.[value] 
            where g.Worksite = @worksite for json path)
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me also realize that inner queries (to produce object arrays within a larger JSON object) must ALSO be `FOR JSON PATH`

Answer (score 1):

For projection in subquery, you can use

```
SELECT t.col1,t.col2
FROM table1 t 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT st.col1,st.col2 
               FROM table2 st
               WHERE st.fcol = t.fcol)
```