# How to put the sum of all rows in each row

Tags: sql-server

this is my query:

```
SELECT clientes.nombre as [NombreCliente], 
       venta.usuario  as [NombreVendedor], 
       SUM((listaventa.precio) ) as [FinalTotal], 
       venta.id as [IdVenta],
       venta.fecha as [Fecha], 
       idproducto as [clave],
       producto.descripcion ,  
       listaventa.precio as [preciounitario], 
       listaventa.cantidad,
       listaventa.total as  [PrecioTtoal] 
 FROM venta  
 JOIN clientes on venta.idcliente = clientes.id  
 JOIN listaventa on listaventa.idventa=venta.id  
 JOIN producto on listaventa .idproducto =producto.id  
WHERE venta.id ='36' 
GROUP BY clientes.nombre, venta.usuario, venta.id, venta.fecha, listaventa.idproducto, producto.descripcion,  listaventa.precio, listaventa.cantidad, listaventa.total
```

Problem is, I don't get is sum, as query is checking id for id, it never return  a sum(listaventa.precio) it returns the same than cantidad*preciou (of every product but it never sum it).  Else if i try it

```
SELECT clientes.nombre as [NombreCliente], 
       venta.usuario  as [NombreVendedor], 
       SUM((listaventa.precio) ) as [FinalTotal], 
       venta.id as [IdVenta],
       venta.fecha as [Fecha], 
       idproducto as [clave],
       producto.descripcion ,  
       listaventa.precio as [preciounitario], 
       listaventa.cantidad,
       listaventa.total as  [PrecioTtoal] 
  FROM venta  
  JOIN clientes on venta.idcliente = clientes.id  
  JOIN listaventa on listaventa.idventa=venta.id  
  JOIN producto on listaventa .idproducto =producto.id  
 WHERE venta.id ='36' 
   AND venta.id IN (SELECT * 
                      FROM listaventa 
                     WHERE idventa = 36)
```

I get this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: You  may want to clarify what you are after since the query as written makes no sense.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  There's no reason anyone would want to know SUM(lista.precio).  El total de los preciounitarios no significa nada.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904314/only-one-expression-can-be-specified-in-the-select-list-when-the-subquery-is-not)

Comment: Instead of `IN (SELECT *` maybe you meant `IN (SELECT id`?

Comment: I don't think so, OMG.  This is more like "How to return the sum of all rows in each row."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, if you're trying to print an order/invoice/receipt/packing slip:

```
select     clientes.nombre as [NombreCliente], venta.usuario as [NombreVendedor], 
           venta.fecha, venta.id as [IdVenta], idproducto as [clave], 
           producto.descripcion, listaventa.precio as [preciounitario], 
           SUM(listaventa.cantidad) as [cantidad], 
           SUM(listaventa.total) as [LineaTotal], 
           (SELECT SUM(listaventa.total) FROM listaventa WHERE idventa = '36') 
           as [VentaTotal]

from       venta 
inner join clientes on venta.idcliente = clientes.id 
inner join listaventa on listaventa.idventa = venta.id 
inner join producto on listaventa.idproducto = producto.id  

where      venta.id ='36'

group by   clientes.nombre, venta.usuario, venta.fecha, venta.id, 
           listaventa.idproducto, producto.descripcion, listaventa.precio
```

Comment: No, i really want to get how is the total of all the products, but i want this sum in all the rows (this is for a crystal report)

Comment: Ah, say no more.  I edited my answer by adding a VentaTotal column.

Comment: Good.  I may have forgotten to include that last column in the group by though, so just add it in if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `listaventa.precio` from your `GROUP BY` clause.

It should generate the correct `SUM` for that field if you allow it to aggregate.

Comment: then i get "Column 'listaventa.idproducto' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: It shouldn't be in the `SELECT` list also.  Remove it. How do you expect to get both the field and the aggregate of the field on the same row?