# "ERROR: Only one expression can be specified in the select list" Linq To Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
var loggedInHours = db.LoginLogs.Where(l => l.UserId == u.Id && l.UserSessionStop != null)
                                                                     .Sum(ls=> ls.UserSessionStart.Subtract(ls.UserSessionStop.Value).Hours)
```

I am trying to calculate Total LoggedIn Hours using this linq query..
But its giving me this error
 "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."
I don't know whats wrong with it..plz help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904314/only-one-expression-can-be-specified-in-the-select-list-when-the-subquery-is-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try if this works:

```
var loggedInHours = db.LoginLogs.Where(l => l.UserId == u.Id && l.UserSessionStop != null)
                      .Select(l=> new { 
                                         StartTime = l.UserSessionStart,  
                                         EndTime = l.UserSessionStop
                                      })
                     .ToList()
                     .Sum(c=> c.StartTime - c.EndTime);
```

btw, Is `UserSessionStop` nullable? If yes, then what will be the value to be subtracted?