# Case Statement in 'IN' clause in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a case statement inside the IN clause.

The Channel column contains three values ACT, REN, REP. I want to select more than 1 values, but I get result with only one value.

```
    select * from tbl
    WHERE tbl.Channel IN (select 
                                    case when @ACT =1 then 'ACT'
                                    when @REN =1 then 'REN' 
                                    when @REP =1 then 'REP' END)
```

What changes should I be doing here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904314/only-one-expression-can-be-specified-in-the-select-list-when-the-subquery-is-not

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag with the platform you are actually using. Those tags have descriptions when you mouse over them; please read them before using them.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I see that a lot recently. Probably due to this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275170/stop-generic-database-questions-from-getting-mysql-as-a-suggested-tag

Comment: @Martin Could be. Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/suggested-tags-both-sql-server-and-mysql-are-suggested-by-the-system and the discussion under Shog's answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips).

Comment: @AaronBertrand hopefully they extend the new tag tips feature to be a bit more intelligent and recognise specific RDBMS platforms so it doesn't warn you when it is already tagged. Then I guess it will be a short step to recognise you have multiple tagged.

Comment: @Martin Yeah, I do sense that it is getting worse and not better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work fine. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f5b1/1)

The only change is removing the `select` so the input to the in clause is 3 values rather than a single row with three columns.

The implicit `else null` if the variable is not 1 does not cause a problem in an `in` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl 
WHERE  tbl.channel IN ( CASE 
                          WHEN @ACT = 1 THEN 'ACT' 
                        END, CASE 
                          WHEN @REN = 1 THEN 'REN' 
                        END, CASE 
                               WHEN @REP = 1 THEN 'REP' 
                             END )
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't end your case. You are returning 3 columns. You only want one.

```
select * from tbl
    WHERE tbl.Channel =  case when @ACT =1 then 'ACT' 
                              when @REN =1 then 'REN'
                              when @REP =1 then 'REP' 
                              else NULL END
```

Comment: Then ACT would be returned first.

Comment: I want to select more than one option out of REn, REP and ACT. Here, I get only 1 value

Answer (score 1):

You can write the clause without a `case` at all:

```
select *
from tbl
where (tbl.Channel 'ACT' and @ACT = 1) or
      (tbl.Channel = 'REN' and @REN = 1) or
      (tble.Channel = 'REP' and @REP = 1);
```

Your `select` statement is not correct and should return an error.  `select` statements in `in` clauses are not allowed to return more than one column.

Comment: When combining AND and OR you really should use parentheses to make the desired logic tree clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that should let you perform the selection without an `IN` operator:

```
select * from tbl
WHERE (tbl.Channel='ACT' AND @ACT=1)
   OR (tbl.Channel='REN' AND @REN=1)
   OR (tbl.Channel='REP' AND @REP=-1)
```

If you must use `IN` operator, you should be able to construct a query with `UNION ALL`, like this:

```
select * from tbl
WHERE tbl.Channel IN (
    select case when @ACT =1 then 'ACT' END FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
    select case when @REN =1 then 'REN' END FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
    select case when @REP =1 then 'REP' END FROM DUAL)
```

[Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7ab90/16)