# The user of Exists in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched an while their are multiple entries for my issue they do not assist me in pinpointing my syntax issue.

the error is

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Here is my code

```
DECLARE @NewUserID INT;
DECLARE @OldUserID INT;
DECLARE @CID INT;
DECLARE @NewMar VARCHAR;
DECLARE @LocalUserID INT;
DECLARE @CallDate DATETIME;

SET @OldUserID = 1891
SET @NewUserID = 1868;
SET @CID = (SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM   contact
            WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 mar
                           FROM   marselect
                           WHERE  userid = @OldUserID
                                  AND mar NOT LIKE '%branch%')
            ORDER  BY NEWID());

SET @LocalUserID = 1868;
SET @CallDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000';


--move account to new owner--
UPDATE contact
SET    mar = (SELECT TOP 1 *
              FROM   marselect
              WHERE  userid = @NewUserID)
WHERE  contactid = @cid;

--add history to the account--
INSERT INTO ContactHistory
            (contactid,
             historydate,
             contactResultID,
             UserID,
             ActivityType,
             Note,
             StartTime,
             Endtime,
             CampaignID,
             QtyPhones)
VALUES     (@CID,
            GETDATE(),
            96,
            @LocalUserID,
            'Move',
            'Account Reassigned to ' + @NewMar + '',
            GETDATE(),
            GETDATE(),
            0,
            NULL);

--add callback to the account--
INSERT INTO callback
            (contactid,
             userid,
             contacthistoryid,
             contactLabelRequestID,
             callbackDate,
             LastcontacthistoryID,
             lastattempt,
             closed,
             closeddate,
             closeduserid,
             callbacktype,
             insertdate,
             callnote,
             hastime)
VALUES      (@CID,
             @NewUserID,
             0,
             NULL,
             @CallDate,
             0,
             NULL,
             0,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             'Call',
             GETDATE(),
             'Call created automatically after account reassigned',
             0)
```

I am not understanding why my query does not work.  It works as a stand-alone query but when I use it in this sense it does not work.  I have other errors of the same type in the code, but I figure that if I can understand and solve one I am confident that I can resolve the others.

the error is on this line-

```
set @CID = (select top 1 * from contact where exists (select top 1 mar from marselect where userid = @OldUserID and mar not like '%branch%') order by newid());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904314/only-one-expression-can-be-specified-in-the-select-list-when-the-subquery-is-not)

Comment: @Allan, the error message is the same, but the reasoning that caused the problem is different.  :)

Comment: @David, Admittedly, it's assignment versus comparison, but the source of the problem is the same: the sub-query is providing multiple columns where a single column is expected.

Comment: thank you all for your input.  Yes it was the same as many others but it was hard to understand the error message.

"the sub-query is providing multiple columns where a single column is expected." was what I was needing to understand the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `*` and keep the `column name` that you want to assign to `@CID`

Also there is no use in keeping `top 1` inside `exists`

```
set @CID = 
(
select top 1 CID --here remove * and keep column name
from contact 
where exists (select mar -- Removed Top 1 here
              from marselect 
              where userid = @OldUserID and mar not like '%branch%') 
order by newid()
);
```