# Paging with LoadSelect fails in ServiceStack OrmLite on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm attempting to accomplish paging in my ServiceStack (4.0.50) services, and I'm running into an issue when <strike>the query has multiple joins</strike> using `LoadSelect`.

In order to filter results for security requirements, my `Get` method pulls info from a custom user session and builds a query. Something like this:

```
public QueryResponse<Foo> Get(Foos request)
{
    var session = SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();

    var q = Db.From<Foo>().LeftJoin<Foo, User>((s, u) => s.UserId == u.Id);

    // Also tried this with no success
    //q.Skip(request.Skip);
    //q.Take(request.Take);
    q.Limit(request.Skip, request.Take);

    // I do filtering based on the request object for searching
    if (request.Price.HasValue)
    {
        q.And(s => s.Price == request.Price);
    }
    // ... and so on ...

    // Then I do filtering based on roles
    if (session.HasRole("OrgAdmin"))
    {
        // Do some filtering for their organization
    }
    else if (session.HasRole("SiteManager"))
    {
        // More filtering here
    }

    // Ordering also...
    if (request.OrderBy.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        q.OrderByFieldsDescending(request.OrderByDesc);
    }
    else
    {
        q.OrderByFields(request.OrderBy);
    }

    var response = new QueryResponse<Foo>
    {
        // This works fine
        Total = (int)Db.Count(q),
        // === Error here ===
        Results = Db.LoadSelect(q)
    };

    return response;
}
```

The count always works fine, and the first page of results always works. However, pulling subsequent pages of results gets the following error: **Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.**

<strike>Unfortunately, I need to apply the filtering, which requires the joins.</strike> Unfortunately I need to load the references and want to avoid a select n+1 situation. I've tried inspecting the SQL expressions in the `q` object, but it doesn't look like there's any way to see what the true final SQL is that's sent to the server.

Any suggestions?

**NOTE:** I'm not using AutoQuery, I just appropriated the `QueryBase<>` and `QueryResponse<>` objects to use the paging and count properties.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904314/only-one-expression-can-be-specified-in-the-select-list-when-the-subquery-is-not).  It may be that a subquery has more than one column in it.  You really need to know what SQL is being generated.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's possible, unless I use the ServiceStack source and try to debug it, which I'd rather not do.

Comment: There is usually a way!  Can you use something like wireshark to inspect packets? http://internationaldatascience.com/using-wireshark-to-viewtrack-sql-server-browser-traffic/  or maybe some logging in SQL Server? I'm sorry I'm not familiar with ServiceStack so don't know how that works.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out this is a problem with the standard `SqlServerDialect.Provider`. Since this is SQL 2012, when I switched to `SqlServer2012Dialect.Provider` in the AppHost it worked as expected.

Comment: By the way, you can know the SQL generated using Db.GetLastSql() (place a try... catch block and call Db.GetLastSql() inside the catch).

Comment: The problem is due to the fact SQL generated before SQL Server 2012 cannot use the LIMIT statement which facilitate SQL generation. Until SQL Server 2008 one must use a complex SQL syntax to do the job.