# Update using case with multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables. I want to update `table1` when the condition is satisfied. The condition here is to check the country in `table 2` and if its `Mex`, then multiply rate i.e. `0.5` to the `price`.

I wrote the following code

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.Price = (SELECT *,
                           CASE table2.Country
                                WHEN 'CANADA' THEN (1 * table2.price)
                                WHEN 'MEXICO' THEN (0.5 * table2.price)
                                ELSE 0
                           END AS Price_Calc
                    FROM table2)
FROM table1;
```

As I run this it gives the below error

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>  Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.

Comment: What about the error don't you understand here? The error is telling you exactly what the problem is; your sub query is returning multiple column (and likely rows). What result would you be expecting `Price` to be set to when you're trying to assign it the value of **every** column and row in the table `table2` and the value of expression for `Price_calc`?

Comment: You need to do a join and use case on your join.  Create select first to test and see results, then change to update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904314/only-one-expression-can-be-specified-in-the-select-list-when-the-subquery-is-not)

Answer (score 0):

Try Like below

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.table1.Price = (SELECT
                           CASE t2.Country
                                WHEN 'CANADA' THEN (1 * t2.price)
                                WHEN 'MEXICO' THEN (0.5 * t2.price)
                                ELSE 0
                           END AS Price_Calc
                    FROM table2 t2
                    WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id -- Here it is suggestion to update target 
                                        -- column based on relation if exists between 
                                        -- ur  tables

                     )
FROM table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Table1 and Table2 are related through IDs:

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.Price = t2.Price 
                    * CASE t2.Country 
                        WHEN 'CANADA' THEN 1. 
                        WHEN 'MEXICO' THEN .5
                        ELSE 0
                      END
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Id = t1.Id
;
```