# Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got this error message when I tried to run this code

```
select *
from Folio_Guest
where FolioID = (
    select *
    from Folio
    where ArrivalDate between '20190101' and '20210901'
)
```

Comment: What about the error don't you understand? You are selecting *, you only want one column.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your point

Comment: `FolioID = (select * ...` - how can `FolioID` = `*`?

Comment: select * from Folio_Guest
where FolioID = (select FolioID from folio where ArrivalDate between '20190101' and '20210901')

Comment: You're still selecting * - how can * (multiple columns) ever match a single value? Select a single column...

Comment: this one did not work too

Comment: I am trying to call folioid from a different table

Comment: So select FolioID, **NOT** "*"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904314/only-one-expression-can-be-specified-in-the-select-list-when-the-subquery-is-not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery needs to return at most one row and only one column.  Perhaps you intend something like this:

```
select fg.*
from Folio_Guest fg
where fg.FolioID in (select f.folioID
                     from Folio f
                     where ArrivalDate between '20190101' and '20210901'
                    );
```

The important changes are:

- The subquery returns just one column, the one that should match to `folioID`.
- The comparison uses `in` rather than `=` so it can match multiple rows, if appropriate.