# Sum of score for each staff

Tags: sql, sum

| ID | Staff1 | Staff2 | Staff1_Score | Staff2_Score | Total_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | Joe | 60 | 60 | 120 |
| 2 | Sam | NULL | 120 | NULL | 120 |
| 3 | Joe | Sam | 40 | 40 | 80 |
| 4 | Joe | NULL | 90 | NULL | 90 |
| 5 | Sam | Joe | 60 | 60 | 120 |
| 6 | Sam | NULL | 100 | NULL | 100 |
| 7 | Joe | NULL | 150 | NULL | 150 |

I have a table like that, this for record staff name and score.

But how can i find the sum of each staff score ?

I can't use sum() to find it out.

```
select sum(Staff1_Score)+sum(Staff2_Score) from table where Staff1='Sam'
```

But the result is wrong.

In table,
Sam = 380
Joe = 400

Thanks for helping to solve this.

Dear

| ID | Date | Staff1 | Staff2 | Staff1_Score | Staff2_Score | Total_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-05-2023 | Sam | Joe | 60 | 60 | 120 |
| 2 | 06-05-2023 | Sam | NULL | 120 | NULL | 120 |
| 3 | 08-05-2023 | Sam | NULL | 80 | NULL | 80 |
| 4 | 12-05-2023 | Joe | Sam | 90 | 90 | 180 |
| 5 | 14-05-2023 | Joe | NULL | 60 | NULL | 60 |
| 6 | 15-05-2023 | Sam | Joe | 100 | 100 | 200 |
| 7 | 16-05-2023 | Joe | NULL | 150 | NULL | 150 |

If I need to count with a period. so how to do that?
example : 1-05-2023 to 12-05-2023

Comment: What does this mean: "I can't use sum"? What exactly have you tried and what didn't work as expected? Please add the outcome you want to get.

Comment: Is the 5th column meant to be staff2_score?

Comment: select sum(Staff1_Score)+SUM(Staff2_Score) FROM table where Staff1='Sam'

Comment: Yes, I correct it

Comment: Your actual problem is one of table design, your data should be properly normalised with a single column for the Staff name and score, then you could easily *sum()* your values. Fix that first before you get too far down a rabbit hole - what happens when you have 50 staff/score columns....?

Comment: Why do you want to sum Staff1_Score and Staff2_Score although your table already has the column Total_Score with exactly this sum? Please show first your sample data as table and then the expected result as another table to prevent confusion. Your query returns 460 as sum for Sam, which is correct. See https://dbfiddle.uk/xX1Ar6HW

Comment: @Raymond https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Because my primary key is id, ID is our job no

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server... Depending on your database, different solutions may be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a query that combines the Staff1 and Staff2 and corresponding score.
After that, query that result summing the scores.
Something like this:

```
SELECT   StaffName,
         SUM(StaffScore)
FROM     (SELECT Staff1                    AS StaffName,
                 COALESCE(Staff1_Score, 0) AS StaffScore,
                 DateColumn
          FROM   table
          WHERE  Staff1 IS NOT NULL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT Staff2                    AS StaffName,
                 COALESCE(Staff2_Score, 0) AS StaffScore,
                 DateColumn
          FROM   table
          WHERE  Staff2 IS NOT NULL
         ) AS UnitedStaffs
WHERE    DateColumn BETWEEN CAST('01-05-2023' AS date) AND CAST('12-05-2023' AS date)
GROUP BY StaffName;
```

I can't imagine the column in your table that reports the date is actually called `date`. Please adjust as necessary.
Furthermore, the `CAST` may need adaption based on your international settings.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: I accidentally put a comma in the middle. Please check again

Comment: sorry,another msg -Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: You didn't mention your RDBMS. It looks like SQL Server. In that case an alias for the inner query is required. Please try again

Comment: @Raymond Please clarify your question which is still much too vague (see comments above, below the question)

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: If I need to count with a period. so how to do that? example : 1-05-2023 to 12-05-2023

Comment: Hi robert, if i nêed to count with a period,how can i do? Thx

Comment: Thanks, ROBERT. but I have one more question. I used your answer in triggers. my sentence is "if update (othercolumn) begin", I have a msg. "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."  after execute

Comment: I'm not a SQL-server expert. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904314/only-one-expression-can-be-specified-in-the-select-list-when-the-subquery-is-not